# Screen stretch's when dismissing keyboard by tapping out side

Tags: ionic-framework, ipod

I have multiple screens which require text inputs from keyboard.
When dismissing the keyboard by tapping outside the keyboard area, all of the screen elements stretch vertically. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your config.xml try adding `<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />`.

Comment: I did try it ,But did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I just  removed the ionic keyboard plugin and everything works fine !!

Comment: If your problem was solved, you can mark this answer as correct by pressing the checkmark to the left.